# Dynamic bundle loading at runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

Consider a bundle in some project packed with webpack and all dependencies to `bundle1.js`:

```
// entry.ts
import * as _ from 'lodash';
// other imported libraries
import { something } from './util';
// other imported bundle project local code

export function doBundleSomething(args: any): any {
  // actually does something necessary
  console.log('doing things');
  return 'whatever result';
}
```

Shell program is another project also packed with webpack and all dependencies to `main.js`, except `bundle1.js`, because it is decided at run time from environment:

```
// main.ts
import * as _ from 'lodash';
// other imported libraries
import { something } from './shell-util';
// other imported shell program local code

// do something useful
const ifBundleNeeded = true; // decided by useful something

if (ifBundleNeeded) {
  const bundlePath = process.env.BUNDLE_PATH; // could be CLI argument
  // somehow load bundle 
  const doBundleSomething = ???

  const result = doBundleSomething({arg: 'hello-bundle'});
  console.log('bundle said', result);
}
```

Should be executed like:

```
BUNDLE_PATH=/opt/path/some-bundle.js node /srv/program/path/main.js
```

Notes:

- bare minimum possible configurations are used for everything
- `tsconfig` targets for both bundles is `es6`
- `typescript` >= 3.x with webpack `awesome-typescript-loader` (i.e. latest and greatest)
- duplication of code in both bundles is unavoidable and acceptable
- security issues are not of concern (like code injection etc.)

How to achieve this behavior with bare minimum configs?

If `BUNDLE_PATH` is known (i.e. hard-coding path, so that webpack sees it) at webpacking of shell program, it works in different variations with `require`, `import()` including `eval("require")()`.

Otherwise, using different alternatives fail at different stages with various errors from `Cannot find module` to `undefined` when used.